# How to show last add cell on UITableview whileloading view or reloading tableview?

Tags: ios, uitableview

all I am doing one chat application, i which i am using `UITable` view to display reply and response from user.in this case after some interval of time i am reloading my tableview to fetch new data from server. But the problem is that after adding new content to table view it will go at the bottom of table view and i have to scroll table view to see that one.or in other case whenever i am reloading my table it will show its first cell on view. Now my question is "is it possible to load last cell of `UITableview` after view gets load or reload table view?"

on search I find this line but it give me error

```
[sTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:sender.tag inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

what is `sender.tag` in this line? // use of undeclared identifier sender

This line working well but scrolling the page which i dont want

```
[table_readText scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES ];
```

Any idea or suggestion would be highly welcome.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 4):

You can also look at the scroll view's `setContentOffset:animated:` method.

Going to the **top** would mean,

```
[self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES];
```

and the **bottom** would be,

```
CGFloat height = self.tableView.contentSize.height - self.tableView.bounds.size.height;
[self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, height) animated:YES];
```

**SECOND option:**

```
scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:
```

Scrolls the receiver until a row identified by index path is at a particular location on the screen.

```
- (void)scrollToRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath atScrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Comment: means? And how to use second one?

Comment: you have to call that method