# Showing the last cell of Tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to show the bottom cells of my Tableview once the data are load I dont want to scroll every time to the bottom of Tableview to see the result

I have try this function in viewDidLoad but it did not work the page load at the top cells

```
if myArray.count > 0 {
               tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(item:myArray.count - 1 , section: 0), at: .bottom, animated: false)
            }
```

Comment: try that in `viewWillAppear` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try use this

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) { [tableView] in
            if myArray.count > 0 {
               tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(item:myArray.count - 1 , section: 0), at: .bottom, animated: false)
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage the usage of the scrollView's `setContentOffset:animated:` method

This answer should help you out: [How to show last add cell on UITableview whileloading view or reloading tableview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22928466/how-to-show-last-add-cell-on-uitableview-whileloading-view-or-reloading-tablevie)